# list of figures numbering

Tags: numbering, report

I'm looking to include the "part" number in the list of figures numbering.

Here is what my List of Figures looks like now:

[image]

I wish instead that each element would show

```
I.1.1 Caption for Figure 1.1 Part I Chapter 1
I.1.2 etc...
I.2.1 etc...
I.2.2 etc...
II.1.1 etc...
II.1.2 etc...
II.2.1 etc...
II.2.2 etc...
```

This, of course, if part of a much larger document. I've include all of my preamble with a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[left=1.0in, right=1.0in, top=1.0in, bottom=1.0in]{geometry}

% including package for figures
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

% indent first paragraph
\usepackage{indentfirst}

% change table of contents and list of figures spacing
\usepackage{titletoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\titlecontents{part}[0em]{\addvspace{.1pc}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{2em}}{} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{chapter}[4em]{\addvspace{.1pc}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{2em}}{} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{section}[6em]{\addvspace{.1pc}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{2em}}{} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection}[9em]{\addvspace{.1pc}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{3em}}{} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{figure}[2.5em]{\addvspace{.1pc}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{2.5em}}{} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

% change spacing of part, chapter, section, and subsection headings
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}[hang]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\color{red}}{Chapter\ \thepart:}{5pt}{}   
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\centering\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\color{blue}}{Section\ \thechapter:}{5pt}{}   
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{12pt}{0pt}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{black}}{\thesection}{5pt}{}   
\titlespacing*{\section}{0em}{12pt}{0pt}

\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\normalfont\large\bfseries\color{black}}{\thesubsection}{5pt}{}   
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{3em}{12pt}{0pt}

% remove new page as start of new chapter
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
\makeatother

% links
\usepackage[linkcolor=black, urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%       End Of Preamble and start of document           %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

    \makeatletter\def\ttl@tocsep{}\makeatother
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures

    \part{Title for Part \thepart\space}
        \chapter{Title for Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter\space}
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{demo}
                \caption{Caption for Figure \thefigure\space Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{demo}
                \caption{Caption for Figure \thefigure\space Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}

        \chapter{Title for Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter\space}
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{demo}
                \caption{Caption for Figure \thefigure\space Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{demo}
                \caption{Caption for Figure \thefigure\space Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}

    \setcounter{chapter}{0}
    \part{Title for Part \thepart\space}
        \chapter{Title for Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter\space}
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{demo}
                \caption{Caption for Figure \thefigure\space Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{demo}
                \caption{Caption for Figure \thefigure\space Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}

        \chapter{Title for Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter\space}
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{demo}
                \caption{Caption for Figure \thefigure\space Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{demo}
                \caption{Caption for Figure \thefigure\space Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for any advice you can give.

Comment: Shall this `part` number occur in the caption too or only in the LoF?

Comment: Only in the LoF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[left=1.0in, right=1.0in, top=1.0in, bottom=1.0in]{geometry}

% including package for figures
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

% indent first paragraph
\usepackage{indentfirst}

% change table of contents and list of figures spacing
\usepackage{titletoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\titlecontents{part}[0em]{\addvspace{.1pc}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{2em}}{} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{chapter}[4em]{\addvspace{.1pc}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{2em}}{} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{section}[6em]{\addvspace{.1pc}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{2em}}{} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection}[9em]{\addvspace{.1pc}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{3em}}{} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{figure}[2.5em]{\addvspace{.1pc}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{2.5em}}{} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

% change spacing of part, chapter, section, and subsection headings
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}[hang]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\color{red}}{Chapter\ \thepart:}{5pt}{}   
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\centering\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\color{blue}}{Section\ \thechapter:}{5pt}{}   
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{12pt}{0pt}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{black}}{\thesection}{5pt}{}   
\titlespacing*{\section}{0em}{12pt}{0pt}

\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\normalfont\large\bfseries\color{black}}{\thesubsection}{5pt}{}   
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{3em}{12pt}{0pt}

% remove new page as start of new chapter
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\let\standardthefigure\thefigure
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thepart.\standardthefigure}
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{10pt}

% links
\usepackage[linkcolor=black, urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%       End Of Preamble and start of document           %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

    \makeatletter\def\ttl@tocsep{}\makeatother
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures

    \part{Title for Part \thepart\space}
        \chapter{Title for Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter\space}
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{demo}
                \caption{Caption for Figure \thefigure\space Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{demo}
                \caption{Caption for Figure \thefigure\space Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}

        \chapter{Title for Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter\space}
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{demo}
                \caption{Caption for Figure \thefigure\space Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{demo}
                \caption{Caption for Figure \thefigure\space Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}

    \setcounter{chapter}{0}
    \part{Title for Part \thepart\space}
        \chapter{Title for Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter\space}
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{demo}
                \caption{Caption for Figure \thefigure\space Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{demo}
                \caption{Caption for Figure \thefigure\space Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}

        \chapter{Title for Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter\space}
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{demo}
                \caption{Caption for Figure \thefigure\space Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{demo}
                \caption{Caption for Figure \thefigure\space Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Edit** Simpler version

It's easier than anticipated ;-)

Use the `\DeclareCaptionListFormat` command to define a new LoF figure entry style, say *partfigure`and`\captionsetup` to active this style

```
\DeclareCaptionListFormat{partfigure}{\thepart.\thefigure}
\captionsetup{listformat=partfigure}
```

No `tocloft` is used in here

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[left=1.0in, right=1.0in, top=1.0in, bottom=1.0in]{geometry}

% including package for figures
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}


\DeclareCaptionListFormat{partfigure}{\thepart.\thefigure}
\captionsetup{listformat=partfigure}
\usepackage{subcaption}

% indent first paragraph
\usepackage{indentfirst}

% change table of contents and list of figures spacing

\usepackage{titletoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\titlecontents{part}[0em]{\addvspace{.1pc}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{2em}}{} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{chapter}[4em]{\addvspace{.1pc}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{2em}}{} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{section}[6em]{\addvspace{.1pc}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{2em}}{} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection}[9em]{\addvspace{.1pc}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{3em}}{} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{figure}[2.5em]{\addvspace{.1pc}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{2.5em}}{} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

% change spacing of part, chapter, section, and subsection headings
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}[hang]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\color{red}}{Chapter\ \thepart:}{5pt}{}   
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\centering\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\color{blue}}{Section\ \thechapter:}{5pt}{}   
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{12pt}{0pt}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{black}}{\thesection}{5pt}{}   
\titlespacing*{\section}{0em}{12pt}{0pt}

\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\normalfont\large\bfseries\color{black}}{\thesubsection}{5pt}{}   
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{3em}{12pt}{0pt}

% remove new page as start of new chapter
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
\makeatother


% links
\usepackage[linkcolor=black, urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%       End Of Preamble and start of document           %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

    \makeatletter\def\ttl@tocsep{}\makeatother
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures

    \part{Title for Part \thepart\space}
        \chapter{Title for Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter\space}
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{demo}
                \caption{Caption for Figure \thefigure\space Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{demo}
                \caption{Caption for Figure \thefigure\space Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}

        \chapter{Title for Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter\space}
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{demo}
                \caption{Caption for Figure \thefigure\space Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{demo}
                \caption{Caption for Figure \thefigure\space Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}

    \setcounter{chapter}{0}
    \part{Title for Part \thepart\space}
        \chapter{Title for Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter\space}
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{demo}
                \caption{Caption for Figure \thefigure\space Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{demo}
                \caption{Caption for Figure \thefigure\space Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}

        \chapter{Title for Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter\space}
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{demo}
                \caption{Caption for Figure \thefigure\space Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{demo}
                \caption{Caption for Figure \thefigure\space Part \thepart\space Chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I will add some lines for reducing the indent of the fig numbers

Comment: Adding the `tocloft` package removed all of the formatting I added using the `titletoc` package... Is there another way around this?

Comment: @Stanton: sure, `\usepackage{tocloft}` before `\usepackage{titletoc}`. I will update

Comment: @Stanton: Updated

Comment: @Stanton: Alright: Happy TeXing then